# Creating DEM from LAS file without using LAStools?

Tags: qgis, dem, lidar, las, qgis-2.12

I want to create a ground model from a *.las file. The LAStools are available in QGIS but limited in use (generation of black diagonal in result file), so I can't use this.

In the GRASS tools I can find the tools `v.lidar.edgedetection`, `v.lidar.growing` and `v.lidar.correction`, to classify the las data. Unfortunately, `v.lidar.edgedetection` gives me a python error. So this isn't working either.

How could I proceed?

Comment: What does the error message state?

Comment: I will check this

Comment: The black line added by LAStools is because they aren't licensed. Not all LAStools are free (including the tool required to create a DEM), without a license they will run but will introduce noise.

Comment: related (.xyz version): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170706/irregular-xyz-point-data-to-raster-tif-lastools-alternative

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to generate a DEM from a las file within QGIS using [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html).

Use [this](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) tutorial to enable FUSION's tools in QGIS (works up to QGIS 2.18 version*). It is written for LAStools, but it is straightforward adapting it.

<sub>*As from QGIS version 3, one can install the plugin (besides the core software) and work from there. See: [Unable to install FUSION in QGIS 3.2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299963/unable-to-install-fusion-in-qgis-3-2/300071#300071).</sub>

Once you manage to activate Fusion, you will need the `GroundFilter` tool for classifying ground points (if the point cloud is not yet classified), and then, `GridSurfaceCreate` to generate the DEM.

[image]

If you don't need to use QGIS, I suggest the following [approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101786/how-to-determine-bare-earth-from-unclassified-las-file/108342#108342), which classifies ground points with the MCC algorithm.

Comment: I installed the latest version of Lastools, but I'm using QGIS 2.12.0-Lyon, in the tutorial their speaking about QGIS 2.2.0 : isn't this a problem? When I try to run "groundfilter" I get the following message : c:\software\LAStools\Groundfilter.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Is this beacause of the version of QGIS I'm using, or did I something wrong during the installation?

Comment: This is because GroundFilter and GridSurfaceCreate are tools from Fusion, not Lastools (Fusion is a different program from Lastools). You said you did not want to use Lastools, because the strips it puts over the DEM. So, you need to install Fusion and link it with QGIS. The Fusion tools will appear under the folder "surface" (see the screenshots). I am using QGIS 2.12.2.

Answer (score 6):

I am using the following procedure in SAGA:
pc_processing_with_saga (Wichmann et al. (2012)) [deprecated link](http://geostat-course.org/system/files/pc_processing_with_saga.pdf),
[new link](https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/saga-gis/SAGA%20-%20Documentation/Tutorials/GEOSTAT_2012/pc_processing_with_saga.pdf)!

If you still want to use the DEM in other programs (like QGIS), export it as GeoTIFF from SAGA when reaching Close Gaps step (I use already classified las files).

In SAGA it works like a charm and it is fast.

Comment: But to work with SAGA you need LAS version 1.2. If you need to convert it from 1.4 version use las2las.exe.

Comment: I have just tried with saga-7.6.2_x64 and there was no need of anything else. Really like a charm and fast!

Answer (score 3):

[`pktools`](http://pktools.nongnu.org/html/index.html), when built with [liblas](http://www.liblas.org/) support, provides functionality to generate DEMs from LAS point clouds. The toolkit provides a program called [`pklas2img`](http://www.nongnu.org/pktools/html/md_pklas2img.html), which rasterises a  LAS/LAZ point cloud using filtering/compositing options. For instance, the following commands would generate a DEM:

```
pklas2img -i input.las -o output_dem_min.tif -comp min -n z -dx 2 -dy 2 -ot Float32
```

Where:

- `comp` is the compositing rule for multiple points in a cell, in this example we use `min`, which retains the pulse with the minimum height for each grid cell. The documentation provides the full list of compositing options.
- `dx`and `dy` are the output resolutions

After this step, it is advisable to filter the DEM, which can be done using [`pkfilterdem`](http://www.nongnu.org/pktools/html/md_pklas2img.html) as follows:

```
pkfilterdem -i output_dem_min.tif -o output_dtm.tif -f promorph -dim 3 -dim 17
```

Where:

- dim is the maximum filter kernel size

Note, this functionality is also available from the Processing Toolbox in QGIS using `pktools` version 2.6.6 (see below):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install PDAL library (with OSGeo4W) and look at this example https://pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/dtm/dtm.html

Answer (score 1):

The [lidR](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR) package is an option if you are comfortable writing some simple R code. The method [grid_terrain](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/grid_terrain.html) will interpolate a digital elevation model (ground surface) from a classified point cloud. Several algorithms are available to do this including `tin` (triangulation) and `knnidw` (k nearest neighbor inverse distance weighting). If your point cloud has no classification, the package also offers a [ground classification function](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/lasground.html).