# Computing grid cell statistics using LiDAR point cloud in QGIS

Tags: qgis, lidar, spatial-statistics, vector-grid

I have a LIDAR data `.laz` file of a DEM and a cell grid vector file. I want to compute grid cell statistics, like mean and variance using the LiDAR data. How can I do this in QGIS?

Comment: Do you have LASTools? Here's a tutorial https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/basic_lidar.html and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181712/creating-dem-from-las-file-without-using-lastools

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With QGIS 3.32 ([see the changelog](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog332/index.html#point-clouds)) you have some native algorithm in the Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), there you can export the point cloud into a raster format, DEM for example and make statistics with the raster data

[image]